# Tableau and SQL workbench returning different results

Tags: sql, tableau-api

[image: SQL workbench result]

I have both SQL workbench and Tableau connected to the same DB and the custom query in Tablea runs fine and the data shows up.  However when I run it on Sql workbench it returns that the DB doesn't exist.

[image: talbeau query]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you post the error message you're receiving and the query you're trying to run?

Comment: Can you run any queries from SQL workbench? Is it just this query that's having problems?

Comment: In 99% of those case you are **not** connected to the same database in the two tools. But the error message `relation "public.change_log"` looks strange. That makes me think you use `from "public.change_log"` instead of `from "public"."change_log"` in your query. Please **[edit]** your question and add the **full** query you are using. [_Formatted_](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) text please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: dateformat/timezone difference?